# QGIS 3.10 create DEM from height contours - the maximum height values of the grid to do not match the maximum height values of the contours

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, contour

[image]I have created a DEM using contours spaced 10 metres via QGIS grid ITN interpolation method based on height (metres) cell size 10 pixels/metres in QGIS, and another grid of 5 pixels cell size. When I load the DEM into QGIS, the maximum height is below that of the highest contour.  Would I have to adjust the grid cell size or other parameters to ensure a closer match with the maximum height of the contours? Or use another interpolation method eg nearest neighbour or IDW?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an image of the area you're talking about, as well as tell us, which CRS both files are in.

Comment: Looks like you need an exact interpolator, then both nearest neighbour and IDW would be good choice. If your hilltops have to be above the nearby contour (which means you need a bit of extrapolation) IDW would serve you better. As another option; I would suggest to look into Thin Plate Spline tool.

Comment: here is a screenshot of the image, both contours and grid lines - in BNG EPSG 27000 projection.